# Stuck Unity desktop Hand icon Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, 15.10

In trying to drag and drop a PNG imagine to my chrome browser window my desktop is in an hung state.

The mouse pointer is now a small hand icon.  I can't click any window buttons.

How to I recover my desktop without rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

You can try reloading the mouse module:

Press Alt + F2 for command execution

1. command (unloads the module)

> gksudo modprobe -r psmouse

2. command (loads the module)

> gksudo modprobe psmouse

If you don't need the chrome session, try killing the chrome window:

Alt + F2 again and then:

> xkill

The mouse cursor should witch to an "X". Click the chrome window to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report for this problem [1].
In the discussion of this bug I found a solution that worked for me:

- Switch to a virtual console (Ctrl + Alt + F3).
- Run `pkill nautilus`.
- Switch back to the desktop (Ctrl + Alt + F2).

[1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rapidsvn/+bug/402892